# Does Hoeffding's inequality apply to sampling from finite populations?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, estimation, sampling, sample-size

Based on Hoeffding's theorem, one could easily find the minimum number of samples required for the inequality $\Pr \left(|\bar{X} - \mathrm{E} [\bar{X}]| \geq t \right) \leq \delta$ to hold as $m=\frac{(b-a)^2\ln\frac{2}{\delta}}{2t^2}$.

However, [this paper from Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=219983) states that Hoeffding's inequality "originally targets sampling from an infinite population", and that it should be "compensated by a factor for a finite population", yielding the sample size as $m_N= \frac{1}{\frac{2t^2}{(b-a)^2\ln\frac{2}{\delta}}+\frac{1}{N}}$, where $N$ is the population size.

Can someone please clarify which of the above sample size equations is actually correct for sampling with replacement from a finite population?

Comment: Did you look to see if one implies the other? Conclusion?

Comment: @cardinal Obviously if N tends to infinity they're equal, otherwise they're not. I'm not sure what you exactly mean by one implying the other.

Comment: Ok. Good start. Now, if $ N $ is finite, how do the two results compare to one another?

Comment: I recognize this question is nearly 10 years old, but the bounds in the Microsoft paper are about sampling *without* replacement.  So the two bounds shouldn't be compared at all.